# How can I emulate pressing CTRL+ALT+PAUSE in my Linux VM using AutoKey?

Tags: virtual-machine, autohotkey, remote-desktop, rdp, autokey

**Question:**
How can I emulate pressing CTRL+ALT+PAUSE in my Linux VM using AutoKey?
I tried a script that has

```
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<alt>+<pause>")
```

in it. But it does not work.

**Background:**
I'm using Windows 10 and RDP to log into a Fedora Linux. Switching 100 times a day.

The RDP connection runs in Windows all the time.

If the RDP window is not in the background but active, I can press CTRL+ALT+PAUSE to go into the VM (Fullscreen). If I am inside the VM I can press CTRL+ALT+PAUSE to go back to Windows.

So far so good. I want only one button. Preferably PAUSE. Windows part is ready already with following script

```
Pause::
If !WinExist("RDP Tool Name")
    MsgBox No Window found
  WinShow, RDP Tool Name
  WinActivate, RDP Tool Name
  Send ^!{CtrlBreak}
Return
```

Is the Linux part maybe not possible because the key combination is cached somewhere before my Linux system can even notice it? Any ideas?

Comment: You can't define a hotkey within another one. Put `F1::Send !^{CtrlBreak}` after `Return` and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, my script was wrong. Somehow it was still working with the "F1::", even though this was just for testing and I forgot to remove it afterwards. But it was not working any more if I was in my Linux (Fullscreen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it without any other new script. I just had to edit the RDP settings: Keyboard -> Use Windows-Hotkeys -> On this Computer